# jQuery use HTML code input text field

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input type="text" field and I want to display the pound sign and then a value

Using

```
val NewPrice1 = '2.5';
jQuery('#price_product_field').val('&pound;' + NewPrice1);
```

But it just displays £ inside the box instead of the actual pound sign.

Comment: You're a bit off http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/pound

Comment: It's `var`, not `val` when you create a **variable** ?

Answer (score 2):

HTML entities doesn't work as a value in inputs, they are only converted when used in the HTML, use the character directly:

```
var NewPrice1 = '2.5';
jQuery('#price_product_field').val('£' + NewPrice1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AaU2J/

Comment: Tried that but it add this sign "Â" before the "£" sign

Comment: @user2001411 - Then you're not using the correct character encoding for your site, it should be UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`var NewPrice1 = '2.5';
jQuery('#price_product_field').html('&pound;' + NewPrice1);`